# Logs printing in server.logs whereas not in the specified file

Tags: java, log4j

My logs are getting printed in server logs where as it is not getting printed in the specfic file which i have given in the log.xml

log.xml

```
<appender  name = "Logs" class = "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param   name = "File"        value = "${jboss.server.log.dir}/Loggers/Logs.log"     />
        <param   name = "DatePattern" value = "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param   name = "Append"      value = "true"         />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%m%n" />
        </layout> 
      </appender>

      <logger name="Log">
    <level value="ALL"/>
     <appender-ref ref="Logs" /> 
   </logger>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by server logs ?

Comment: logs generated by jboss server.

Comment: Is this log.xml inside an application or in jboss? Where do you specify the 'specified file'?

Comment: log.xml is in jboss